# Compute $\int_C{x\,\mathrm dz-z\,\mathrm dy+y\,\mathrm dz}$ where $C \subset \mathbb R$ and $\gamma(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, 2t)$ with $t \in [0,2\pi]$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Compute
$$\int_{C}{x\,\mathrm dz-z\,\mathrm dy+y\,\mathrm dz}$$
where $C \subset \mathbb R$ and $\gamma(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, 2t)$ with $t  \in [0,2\pi]$

The textbook im using does not show much computation examples and i couldn't find any examples online. Not even sure how to start.

Comment: how is related $\gamma$ here with the exercise? If $C:=[a,b]$ then $\int_C xdz=x(b-a)$...

Comment: $\gamma$ defines a set of paramatric equations for some path for $(x,y,z)$. i.e. $x = \cos t$ from which you find $dx = -\sin t\ dt$, etc.   You are going to replace $(x,y,z)$ and $(dx,dy, dz)$ with their corresponding forms from the parametric equations, and turn your integral in multiple variables into an integral in terms of $t.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I suppose that $C$ is a path in $\mathbb{R}^3$  ( not $\mathbb{R}^3$) and $\gamma$ is its parametric equation.

In this case, on the path, we have:

$$
x=\cos t \quad \rightarrow \quad dx=\sin t \;dt
$$
$$
y=\sin t \quad \rightarrow \quad dy=-\cos t \;dt
$$
$$
z=2t\quad \rightarrow \quad dz=2dt
$$

Substituting you find an integral on $t$:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} (2\cos t +2t\cos t +2 \sin t)dt
$$